# First order, non-linear ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, quaternions, nonlinear-analysis

I am solving the following equation:
$$f(x)^2+\frac{f(x)^2}{f'(x)^2}=h(x)$$

for a known function $h(x)\geq 0, x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm asking for help with:

1. Identifying this ODE in terms of well-known ODE types (Ricatti equation, Bernoulli eqation, etc.).
2. Solving the equation.
3. Proving the existence and uniqueness for Cauchy problems (I think Peano's theorem applies here, but I would be grateful for confirmation).
4. Solving for special cases. So far with Mathematica I managed to get a solution for $h(x)=const$. and $h(x)=x^2$. If you can generate more solutions, I will be very grateful.

Thanks, Michał

EDIT:

E4.1 A solution for $h(x)=x^n$ seems achievable.

E2.1 I have been trying to solve this equation since 2 months now. One path that I did not explore fully is to factor the equation. Putting $h(x)=-g(x)^2$ we can write
$$f(x)^2+\frac{f(x)^2}{f'(x)^2}+g(x)^2=0$$
Using quaternions we could factor this as
$$(if(x)+j f(x)/f'(x)+k g(x))(-if(x)-j f(x)/f'(x)-k g(x))=0$$
Which would have the same solution as the following quaternion ODE (this  step is "an uneducated guess") 
$$if(x)+j f(x)/f'(x)+k g(x)=0$$
and then to recover the solution I consider I simply take the real part.
Does this make any sense for the quaternion experts?

E2.2 With some substitutions one can recover the form I posted here around 2 months ago [(Almost Abel Form)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3568475/non-linear-ode-almost-abel-equation-of-first-kind)